# Format string syntax with several field specifications and conditional statement; value error

Tags: python, python-3.x, formatting

I have a list `mylist = [1, 2, 3]` and a number `n` which I want to print in a specific way:

> {n} {book or books} read ok: {mylist elements one by one separated by commas)

for example:

> 1 book read ok: 1 , 2, 3
>
> 2 books read ok: 1 , 2, 3

The decision of printing book or books depends on `n`, i.e. if n is 1 then print book, else print books. The code for achieving that is:

```
print("{:s}", "book" if n == 1 else "books")
```

For printing the elements of the list the code is:

```
print(*mylist, sep=' , ')
```

But, I am having problems trying to combine all of this into the desired output with including `.format` for displaying `n` as described above.

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
print("{0} {:s} read ok: {1}".format(n, *mylist, sep=' , '), "book" if n == 1 else "books")
```

which gives `ValueError: cannot switch from manual field specification to automatic field numbering`

Comment: And what don't you understand about that message? You have three placeholders, `{0}`, `{:s}` and `{1}`, and Python can't figure out what you expected to go where!

Comment: @jonrsharpe Well, however on-point and informative the error message was, I did not know how to overcome it and achieve my goal. Hence, my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dissected call to `print()`:

```
print(
    "{0} {:s} read ok: {1}".format(
        n,  # 1st argument to format
        *mylist,  # mylist unpacked as positional arguments to format
        sep=' , '  # a keyword argument to format
    ),  # Formatted string, the 1st argument to print
    "book" if n == 1 else "books"  # 2nd argument to print
)
```

The error is a result of mixing manual and automatic field specifications, as it very clearly states. Don't mix manual (`"{0}"` etc). with automatic (`"{}"`). In your string you have 0, automatic and 1. There's no sane way to decide which positional argument the automatic should be, and so the error is raised.

From [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax):

> If the numerical arg_names in a format string are 0, 1, 2, ... in sequence, they can **all be omitted (not just some)**

A working print in this case could be:

```
print("{} {} read ok: {}".format(
    n,
    "book" if n == 1 else "books",
    ', '.join(str(i) for i in mylist)
))
```

The format string is equal to:

```
"{0} {1} read ok: {2}"
```

Comment: Quick follow-up: could you briefly explain why the `{:s}` is not needed? Confused how it did work previously in isolation with that `:s`

Comment: Depends on your isolated test. The part after the colon is the [format specification](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax), e.g. in `"{:s}"` it is the `s`. [`s` is the default presentation type for string types and may be omitted](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language). Hence it equals `"{}"` for string types. For integers the default presentation type is `d`, for example.